# Read big blob (excel type) data sequentially

Tags: java, excel, buffer, spreadsheet

I hav a big excel file that is stored as a blob in the database (`Oracle`).
If I read the whole file into the memory I get `OutOfMemoryException`.

My solution looks like this: read one page of data from the database and parse it line by line (and here I mean Excel line - so the framework should be able so convert only parts of a spreadsheet). Then check the last whole line that has been read (the size of the lines can vary, so I can not predict the number of bytes in a line, so the chunks would have the last line cut in two parts) and get the next chunk from there.

I need an open source `java` `Excel` library that can accomplish this.

**Questions**:

- do you have a better solution?
- if not which libraries can read an excel sequentially?

Comment: I have already checked this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858941/reading-a-range-of-excel-sheet-data-using-poi, and I my problem with it is that I do not know the range of line, and I do not know wherteh POI can read corrupted excel files (i.e. chinks of an excel file)

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this.  Excel files aren't random access or streamable like csv afaik.  I had to up my heap space to deal with excel file conversions.

Comment: I can have millions of entries in that file ... therefore changing the heap size is not an option for me.

Comment: are you sure it's an excel workbook and not just csv/tsv?

Comment: Our application saves it as Excel, so I am pretty sure it is an excel workbook ...